# My uploaded artifact does not list its dependencies in Apache Archiva

Tags: maven, dependencies, archiva

I have installed Apache Archiva to manage my personal artifacts. However, I am now experiencing a weird behavior that my uploaded artifact does not list its dependencies on Archiva view.

Here is the pom.xml file of my sample project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.my.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>D:\samplePrj</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.json</artifactId>
            <version>20230403</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>advantco-repository</id>
            <url>http://myserver.com:8082/repository/myrepository/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

This project has two dependencies

- org.json
- httpclient5

I then uploaded `mysample-1.0.1.jar` to Archiva successfully.
But, I found that the pom file in the artifact on Archiva is missing dependencies section as the image below.
[image]

And, in the Dependencies tab, it shows nothing.
[image]

Am I missing something? I am expecting it should list the dependencies as the `common-logging` artifact.
[image]